# Are there probability density functions with the following properties?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, numerical-methods, nonlinear-optimization

Given two distinct and continuous probability density functions on real numbers, $f_0$ and $f_1$ consider the following set of density functions:

$$\mathscr{G}_0=\left\{g_0:\int_{\mathbb{R}}\log\left(\frac{g_0(y)}{f_0(y)}\right)g_0(y)\mathrm{d}y\leq \epsilon_0\right\} $$ and $$\mathscr{G}_1=\left\{g_1:\int_{\mathbb{R}}\log\left(\frac{g_1(y)}{f_1(y)}\right)g_1(y)\mathrm{d}y\leq \epsilon_1\right\} $$

for some sufficiently small $\epsilon_0$ and $\epsilon_1$ such that $\mathscr{G}_0$ and $\mathscr{G}_1$ are also distinct. In other words any density $g_0\in \mathscr{G}_0$ is not an element of $\mathscr{G}_1$ and vice verse. Note that $f_0$ and $f_1$ are assumed to be positive so that the terms $\log(g_i/f_i)$, $i\in\{0,1\}$, are well defined.

> **Question:** Are there a pair of density functions $g^*_0\in \mathscr{G}_0$ and $g_1^*\in \mathscr{G}_1$ such that
>
> $$g^*_0=\arg\sup_{g_0\in \mathscr{G}_0}\left(\inf_{u\in \mathbb{R}}\ln \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\frac{g_1^*(y)}{g_0^*(y)}\right)^u g_0(y)\mathrm{d}y\right)$$ and $$g^*_1=\arg\sup_{g_1\in \mathscr{G}_1}\left(\inf_{u\in \mathbb{R}}\ln \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\frac{g_1^*(y)}{g_0^*(y)}\right)^u g_1(y)\mathrm{d}y\right)?$$

**EDIT:**

I *guess* the problem simplifies **considerably** to finding $g_0^*\in \mathscr{G}_0$ and $g_1^*\in \mathscr{G}_1$ which solves:

$$(g^*_0,g^*_1)=\arg   \sup_{(g_0,g_1)\in \mathscr{G}_0\times \mathscr{G}_1} \inf_{ u\in  [0,1]}\ln \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\frac{g_1(y)}{g_0(y)}\right)^u g_0(y)\mathrm{d}y$$

I was thinking about Lagrangian type of optimization but I doubt one can get a closed form expression. How can one find a solution?

Any comments are welcomed. Numerical solutions are also very much welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where does this problem come from?

Comment: @Michael Grant okay. The $\inf_{u\in[0,1]}...$ term is a the chernoff distance multiplied by $-1$. Basically I want to find two density functions one from each set, such that the chernoff distance is minimized.

Comment: Regarding your claim that this question merits a convex-optimization tag: I am not seeing it. Convex optimization models cannot involve nonlinear equations *even if the functions involved are convex/concave*. As for the recent EDIT, I do not see any evidence that this is a convex model, either. I could be wrong about this last point but I would say the onus is on you to demonstrate convexity. Thus I would suggest omitting the tag.

Comment: @MichaelGrant so the tags are then okay)) sorry may be I meant differently.

Comment: All is well with the tags on this post. Sorry I cannot help you with the solution. Good luck!

Comment: @MichaelGrant thank you for the comments.